# how to jump to specific text or paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

Ho do I make a link to specific text or paragraph in a page. I can't use id or anchor name cause Its external web page so I can't edit it.

i.e.

```
<a href="#But also the leap">This is the link I want to use</a>
```

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centurie.
>
> **But also the leap** into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
>   release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
>   recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: Given you can't add anchors/ids, you're probably looking at JS. Is adding a custom script to the page feasible?

Comment: JS is what I would try, but it is going to have some limitations like cross-domain permissions if the page isn't on your domain.

Comment: Page isn't on my domain as I said its external website page so I can't add javascript or ids to that page.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the target page already contains anchor tags or element IDs that match what you want, what you want to do is not possible without cooperation from the recipient page -- you'll have no way to either determine the desired scroll position or to set it in the linked site.

> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious documents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy